# Any Database issues using VARCHAR as an ID

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm building a database and want to use VARCHAR as the ID/Primary Key for some tables so it's more user friendly.  I know historically there were system limitations/slow downs, so using the smallest possible data type was good practice.

With current system hardware, has this changed?  I mean, should we still practice using small data types or is this a thing of the past?

Thanks,

Comment: The larger the data you use for an index, the larger the index, and the more memory it will need to accommodate it. That's it. Maybe if you were to actually describe the data and the indexing strategy we'd be able to comment more effectively and/or offer alternatives.

Comment: For smaller tables like RegionID, DepartmentID, or PaymentID.  Instead of numerical values, use SW for south west.  WetUtilities for department.  ACH for PaymentID.

Comment: Thanks everyone.  (minus the guy that downvoted my question :P)

Comment: My own view is that these sorts of things should have no meaning beyond the scope of the database - but that's just me.

Answer (score 2):

It is not the end of the world.  But `VARCHAR()` is discouraged for primary keys for the following reasons:

- They generally occupy more space than integers.  This makes little difference in the primary table, but the space usage is multiplied for foreign key references.
- They are (generally) variable length.  This adds a slight overhead to indexes.  Not much, but why bother?
- They are (generally) not ordered.  The table is sorted by the primary key, so this increases the chances of page splits and fragmentation.
- It is possible that they can change.  I just find cascading foreign key relationships to be a bad sign in a data model.

I would recommend an auto-incremented primary key, with a unique index on the `varchar()` column, and all foreign references using the primary key.

Comment: While I do see a lot of people commenting on mysql index fragmentation, I've yet to see any actual statistics or tools that can generate stats about this or quantify it any meaningful way.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this answer supplementary to @GordonLinoff's.

While your stated examples of strings to be indexed are reasonable, you should be aware that:

- Indexing a `VARCHAR(X)` is equivalent to indexing a `CHAR(X)` in that the entry in the index is constant.
- Indexing a string type in a utf8/utf8mb4 collation means that the length is 3X or 4X respectively.

So if you were to index a utf8mb4 `VARCHAR(255)` column each entry would require roughly 1kB of index space/memory. [Subject to [key length constraints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-restrictions.html) which may be more or less than that.]

One is not definitively better than the other as there are tradeoffs you'll have to make either way. Surrogate keys can keep index sizes small, but require additional application logic. Natural keys are more natural to use, but often require more index space.